# Which Mac for Web development + iOS development

Tags: mac, hardware-recommendation

I'm a Windows user, but I'm looking to get a portable Mac for web development and iOS development.

I will be running sublime 3, Xcode and probably Nginx or XAMPP as my server. Would the 11-inch MacBook Air be a suitable machine? If not, what would be the minimum spec machine.

Comment: Regarding your use of webserver - I found it to be worth using the Apache server and php that comes installed with OSX. Avoids messy Xampp installations and multiple webservers running side-by-side. Great guide [here](http://mallinson.ca/post/osx-web-development/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shopping.

Comment: @DanielLawson it's not so much shopping. It was the capabilities a machine had as someone unfamiliar with macs and Mac programs. It was asked and suitably answered I felt quite a long time ago. I'm not sure why someone decided to post an answer this morning,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 11-inch MacBook Air would more than suit your needs as far as specs go.

But, the screen size makes it hard for developers who are used to multiple monitors or windows side-by-side.

On my 11-inch Air, I normally use apps in full-screen mode and use gestures to switch between them quickly, but I sacrifice being able to have side-by-side applications.

You might consider an 11-inch Air with an alternate monitor (or more than one) for when you can sit at a desk and get serious.

Answer (score -2):

I can warmly recommend you the [Apple MacBook Air MD711LL/B](http://computerchecker.blogspot.com/2014/10/apple-macbook-air-md711llb-116-inch.html)

Sure it has its price, but it's definitely worth it IMO.